# Global and extern in Class

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

What if I declare a class variable as `extern` so that it can access some `global` variable declared in some other file? Does such a scenario come up anytime or is it just a hypothetical case?

Lets say I have a header file `global.h`

```
extern int myglobalint;
```

and I have a cpp file `my.cpp`

Here I declare a class `A`

```
class A{
    //use that variable here....is it possible
}
```

Comment: If it's for the sole purpose of understanding - why don't you just test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it comes up from time to time, particularly in messy code. :D

Perhaps a more C++-like style would be to keep these kinds of variables together in a class, eg in global.h:

```
class Global { // You can do this with 'struct' & omit 'public'
public:
    static int myglobalint;
};
```

And in global.cpp:

```
int Global::myglobalint = 0xbeef;
```

There's really no advantage doing it with an extern or class members - but unless it's some kind of global setting or flag, if you're resorting to storing state globally you probably need to put some thought into your design.

If you really do need global variables, for example, state or configuration that really has no other place to live, I would choose the class-static approach over a mess of extern's.

Comment: ok thanks nevelis....I understand...since class is new toy added in C++..you intend to group such objects into a single global class and keep its access static...so that variable can be accessed anywhere and its memory belongs to the class and not the objects of that class..thanks...i'll try something on it and get back if i have problems.

Comment: Also make sure you understand the difference between `static` in & out of a class definition.  If it's in the class definition, it means the field belongs to the class, and must be defined in a source file somewhere only once (similar behavior to extern), but outside it means it's not visible to anything outside the source file (the exact opposite of extern!).  If you have a `static int foo;` field in a header file that isn't part of a class definition, every file that includes a copy of that file will have its own copy of `foo`.

Comment: Hi @nevelis ..a function is extern by default right? so it can be accessed from any translational unit. What happens in a class....is the function extern here as well.

So lets say i define a class which has public functions...now that is accessible outside the class using the object. But if i add static to it..then i can call that function without instantiating an object...then does extern play role...here i think it will clash with static...but anything from ur end.

Comment: You can't use extern in a class definition.  The way it works - with a non-static class method, there's a hidden `this` pointer passed as the first parameter.  So if you had `class Foo { void Bar( int x, int y ); }` - the parameters to bar are actually `Bar* this, int x, int y`.  Static class methods omit the `this` pointer.  If the method is const (eg: `void Bar( int x, int y ) const;`) then the parameter passed in is `const this`.

Comment: `extern` can be used though inside translation units - so if I had `extern int x` inside file1.c and file2.c, and `int x = 5;` later in file2.c, file1.c can see the same `x` without including a common header file.  Hence my comment about messy code. :D